# View content with parameters in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Hello all I have a problem that my information is not being send to my view file.
What mistake do I have?

My Model:

```
public function viewbds($duanid, $bdsid)
    {

    $q = $this->db->query("SELECT bds.tenduan, bds.id, bds.tieude FROM bds WHERE bds.tenduan=$duanid AND bds.id=$bdsid);

         if($q->num_rows() > 0)
             return $q->result();
         return false;          

    }
```

My Controller:

```
public function chothue($duanid, $bdsid)
        {

                 $this->load->model('admin_model');
             $date[chothue] = $this->admin_model->viewbds('$duanid', '$bdsid'); 
             $this->load->view('admin/view', $data);
        }
```

My View: **admin/chothue/1/1**

```
<?php foreach($chothue as $d) { ?>
                        <tr>
                        <td><?php echo $d->id; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $d->tenduan; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $d->tieude; ?></td>
                    <?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$this->db->query("SELECT bds.tenduan, bds.id, bds.tieude FROM bds WHERE bds.tenduan=$duanid AND bds.id=$bdsid")->get();
```

Don't forget to use ->get()

AND use active record

```
$this->db->select("tenduan, id, tieude")->from("bds")->where("tenduan", $duanid)->where("id", $bdsid)->get();
```